# SQL Anywhere, Entity Framework 4 and Transactions

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, transactions, sqlanywhere

I have a process in my program that uses an Entity Framework 4 EDM.  The entity context object contains function imports for calling stored procedures.

The process receives a batch of data from a remote server.  The batch can consist of data for any of our tables / data types (each data type is stored in its own table).  The batch can also contain data for the same row multiple times.  It has to handle this as a single insert (for the first occurance) and one or more updates (for each subsequent occurance).  The stored procedures therefore implement an upsert operation using the `INSERT ... ON EXISTING UPDATE` command.

Our code basically determines which stored procedure to call and then calls it using the entity context object's method for that stored procedure.  Then entire batch has to be done in a single transaction, so we call `context.Connection.BeginTransaction()` at the beginning of the batch.

There is one data type that has millions of rows.  We need to load that data as quickly as possible.  I'm implementing logic to import that data type using the `SABulkCopy` class.  This also needs to be a part of the single transaction already started.  The issue is that I need to pass an `SATransaction` to the `SABulkCopy` class's constructor (there is no way to set it it using properties) and I don't have an `SATransaction`.  `context.Connection.BeginTransaction()` returns a `DBTransaction`.  I tried to cast this into an `SATransaction` without success.

What's the right way to get the `SABulkCopy` object to join the transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We gave up on the `SABulkCopy` class.  It turns out that it doesn't do a bulk load.  It creates an `SACommand` object that executes an `INSERT` statement and inserts the rows one at a time.  And it does it inefficiently, to boot.

I still needed to get at the `SATransaction` associated with the `DBTransaction` returned by `context.Connection.BeginTransaction().`  I was given some reflection code that does this in response to another question I posted about this:

```
SATransaction saTransaction = (SATransaction) dbTransaction.GetType() 
                                                           .InvokeMember( "StoreTransaction", 
                                                                          BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic   | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod |
                                                                          BindingFlags.Instance         | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.NonPublic, 
                                                                          null, dbTransaction, new object[ 0 ] );
```

The program does what it needs to do.  It's unfortunate, though, that Microsoft didn't make the `StoreTransaction` property of the `EntityTransaction` class public.

Comment: I know this is old, but could you tell me how did you find out that the SaBulkCopy creates and SACommand and executes Insert statment ... ? 

By the way, what was your solution when you decided to give up on SaBulkCopy? Thanks

Comment: Yes, this was a long time ago.  I may have used a decompiler like .Net Reflector to look at the decompiled code to figure out what was happening during the SaBulkCopy. I think the code is an open source project, so you can look it up.  Sorry, I'm not in that position any more, so I can't remember. I seem to remember we had to write code that inserted the data a row at a time (no getting around that) into a temp table without indexes and then updated the main table from that table, then dropped the temp table afterwards. We also did it all in one transaction.

Comment: Thanks alot for you anwser @Tony Vitabile

Comment: I think that the SaBulkCopy would create an `SaCommand`, insert a row, discard the `SaCommand`, and then repeat for each row. We wrote the code so it created one `SaCommand` object that it would reuse for all of the rows. For one or two rows, not much of an improvement, but for millions of rows, the improvement would be significant.